# How to display 2 variables in a single cell Mysql

Tags: php, cell

I would like to display two picture variables in a single cell

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6vNp.gif

```
$result = mysqli_query($query) 
  or die(mysql_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "<table border='0' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: white;'>";
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     $Limg = $row['Limg'];
     $Limgt = $row['Limgt'];
           if ($i==0) {
                       echo "<tr>\n";
                      }
            echo "<td align='center' width='140'>" . "<img src=\"{$row['Limgt']}\">" ."</td>";
           echo "<td align='center' width='40'>" . "<img src=\"{$row['Limg']}\">" ."</td>";
           $i++;
           if ($i == $items) {
                              echo "</tr>\n";
                              $i = 0;
                              }
 }
 echo '</table>';
 }else {
   echo 'no records found';
 }
?>
```

What am I missing

Comment: two images should in two tr then you will have your expected output

Answer (score 0):

You're putting them each in their own cell () - try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query) 
  or die(mysql_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "<table border='0' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: white;'>";
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     $Limg = $row['Limg'];
     $Limgt = $row['Limgt'];
           if ($i==0) {
                       echo "<tr>\n<td>";
                      }
            echo "<img src=\"{$row['Limgt']}\">";
            echo "<img src=\"{$row['Limg']}\">";
           $i++;
           if ($i == $items) {
                              echo "</td></tr>\n";
                              $i = 0;
                              }
 }
 echo '</table>';
 }else {
   echo 'no records found';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are making them in two TDs so you have to make them in one TD like that

```
   echo "<td align='center' width='140'>
             <img src=\"{$row['Limgt']}\">
             <img src=\"{$row['Limg']}\">
         </td>";
```